# Is the word meaning application a good candidate for using Redis?

Tags: java, nosql, redis

I have started playing with redis a week back and now I want to built a simple word meaning

application which uses Redis as a datastore. The application will find a list of meanings

for a given word. I have few questions before I start writing the app :

1. Is this a good app to use Redis or using RDBMS like mysql is better? I thought it was a good example because I can have structure in redis like

   Map <String, List <String>> wordWithMeanings
2. Can I create a Map <String,List <String>> in redis? If yes how?

Thanks

Shekhar

Answer (score 0):

A redis set or list should do what you need, with the word as the key to the list/set and the meanings as items in the list/set. A hash is also an option if you want to have a sub key for each meaning to make editing easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Redis can be used for anything. The difference between Redis and say MySQL is that in redis, you need to know the exact position of the data you want.
2. To make a list, just do rpush KEY VALUE. That will add a key to the end of the list. To access it do: lindex KEY 0 (END #[use llen KEY to find out]) So, the layout of this would look like (See http://cl.ly/3ldR)

Hope this helped